# web.xml error page relative host

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web

How do I specify a error-page in my web.xml which redirects to a relative page not hosted on the application server?

For example

Web Server (Host A) forwards to Application Server (Host B). Application Server fails and uses the error page in web.xml to return a page that exists on the Web Server (Host A).

In web.xml I don't want to hardcode the Host A server name and should therefore be relative, ie /error/errorpage.html

but I don't see how to achieve that using the "location" field in the errorpage.

Comment: You can load a dummy HTML in your webapp , have that mapped in web.xml and on load of dummy page, redirect user to whatever external error page you want using javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can't make a url relative to another server the way you want to, the server is not psychic.

You will have to build a fully qualified url and return it based on the details in the `HttpServletRequest` that caused the exception on the back end server if you want the calling server to present the error page.